# Understanding index_buffer_size better

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have set the index_buffer_size to 20% of the total memory allocated to Elasticsearch. What happens when I have indexed so many documents that it fills up the index buffer before an index refresh is triggered?

As I understand, the index buffer is cleared after a successful index refresh for which we set an interval (index.refresh_interval). But if the interval has not elapsed and I have managed to fill up the buffer, does Elasticsearch trigger an index refresh by itself because there is no space left in the buffer?

Or does something else happen?